# Misunderstanding in use of class variables from a header file

Tags: c++, class, header-files

```
struct TodoItem
{
    std::string todo;
};

const int MAX_STACK_SIZE = 5;

class TodoStackArray
{
  public:
    TodoStackArray();  //confusion here<---
    bool isEmpty();  
    bool isFull();  
    void push(std::string todoItem);  
    void pop();  
    TodoItem* peek();  

    /* for grading purposes we need these following methods */  
    int getStackTop()    { return stackTop; }  
    TodoItem** getStack() { return stack; }   

  private:  
    int stackTop;  
    TodoItem* stack[MAX_STACK_SIZE];  
};
```

Above, is some declarations and a class from a header file for a current assignment. Our duty was to implement a stack program using this header file. However, I am a little confused as to the purpose of the `TodoStackArray()` in the Header File. Is this supposed to be a base constructor? Am I supposed to use it for anything??

I understand that this is somewhat situation specific but given that stack Arrays are STL I figured you might all be able to provide some insight. Thanks!

In case you want to see what I did with this header file...

```
TodoStackArray::TodoStackArray() //This, unsurprisingly, produces an error.
{
    stackTop = -1;
    stack[stackTop];
}

bool TodoStackArray::isEmpty()
{
    return (stackTop == -1);
}

TodoItem* TodoStackArray::peek()
{
    if(stackTop ==-1)
    {   
        cout<< "Stack empty, cannot peak."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        return(stack[stackTop]);
    }
}
bool TodoStackArray::isFull()
{
    return(stackTop == 4);
}

void TodoStackArray::push(std::string todoItem)
{
    if(stackTop >= 5)
    {
        cout<<"Stack full, cannot add new todo item."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        stack[stackTop++];
        stack[stackTop]->todo = todoItem;
    }
}

void TodoStackArray::pop()
{
    if(stackTop == -1)
    {
        cout<<"Stack empty, cannot pop an item."<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        stackTop--;
    }
}
```

Also, to be clear, we were not provided driver software. They will be assessing from their own stuff so we have to write our own driver software to test our functions. Hence the lack of any Main implementation.

Comment: From a fast reading I can see you are doing `stack[stackTop];` which is equal to `stack[-1];`. What are you trying to do with that instruction?

Comment: I receive an error along the lines of;
"return type specification for constructor invalid" @ 8:30, 
void TodoStackArray::TodoStackArray()

Comment: _TodoStackArray()" in the Header File. Is this supposed to be a base constructor? Am I supposed to use it for anything??_ TodoStackArray() is the constructor which is used to initialize the instance of the class. You can use this to initialize your class members here.

Comment: @c.bear I am just trying to initialize the variables in TodoStackArray(), as I believe I need to reference it but am unsure to what extent. 

My logic being that; I reference the stack at any point in which I am pushing it or peeking or so on, and don't need to do anything further as it is declared in the header file. 

However, I am certain something is necessary to be done with the "TodoStackArray" it is just not clear to me what.

Comment: If your error is `return type specification for constructor invalid`, you probably wrote `void` before the constructor, which you did not do in the snipped shown here. So remove the `void`.

Comment: And don't use the numbers `4` and `5` in your code, use `MAX_STACK_SIZE-1` and `MAX_STACK_SIZE`.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Removing Void resolved that issue, thanks!

Comment: @Pramodab So in this case it is merely to prevent initialization of junk values in the variables being passed from the header file?

Comment: @sam it's ok to intialize variables inside your constructor. the problem is that with the instruction `stack[stackTop];` you are doing nothing. You are simply accessing the stack value at index `stackTop` (which is -1) without assigning/saving a value.

Comment: @c.bear Aha, I see what you are saying. Would it be more correct to say, stack[stackTop++]->todo = todoItem; ?

Or, in attempting to increment, should I make a temporary variable and move along the array in that manner?

Comment: @sam : What you may have missed is that, once your constructor is called, the object has already been **allocated**, so your array already exists **in memory**. This may clear things out a bit (I hope). :)

Comment: @Sam yes its important to avoid doing wrong thing like an uninitialized object.

Comment: May I also add that ```stack``` is an array of **pointers** to ```TodoItem```, not an array of items really. So accessing a item will require more work on your side, I'm afraid (dynamically allocating todo items).

Comment: Hint: right now ```stack[stackTop]->todo``` pretty much means "*kaboom!*" (don't mind asking if you need help on that as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `TodoStackArray::TodoStackArray()` really is your class' default constructor.

What you are supposed to do with it just as with any default constructor:

> How are the class members supposed to be *initialized* if I create a new  `TodoStackArray`?

The answer depends on what your class is supposed to look like in its initial state.

In you situation, "by default" a stack is **empty**. Setting the `stackTop` to -1 was not a bad idea and the rest of your implementation is consistent with that (`stackTop == -1` clearly means "empty stack").

The odd thing that happens in your constructor is this:

```
stack[stackTop];
```

What is, according to you, the purpose of this line? You are **reading** the value in your array at a negative index, and we all know this kind of things never end well.

Constructors are made to initialize your data. Here you are reading something you didn't initialize at an index that doesn't exist. Doesn't make much sense, does it? :)

Just get rid of this line and you should be able to move on. Here is an equivalent implementation using [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) (which are considered nicer):

```
TodoStackArray::TodoStackArray() : stackTop(-1)
{
    // notice: no body required here
}
```

Have fun!